# Sticky navbar vertical bullet points

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to create a sticky navbar but it's just shows up as vertical bullet points with links. Here's the code I'm using:

```css
/* Spacing & Border of First Link in Navigation */
    .tabs-inner .section:first-child ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 0 solid #eeeeee;
    }

    /* Background & Border of Navigation */
    .tabs-inner .widget ul {
    background: #999999;
    border: 0px solid #eeeeee;
    text-align: center  !important;
    }

    /* Font, Colour & Border of Links */
    .tabs-inner .widget li a {
    font: normal normal 14px Arvo;
    color: #333333;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    }

    /* Font & Colour of Rollover Links */
    .tabs-inner .widget li.selected a, .tabs-inner .widget li a:hover {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
 
    /* Centre Navigation */
    .tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li{
    display: inline;
    float: none;}
```

```html
<div id="stickynavbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="home" href="LINK">Home</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried different versions and whatever I do trying to create a navbar it keeps coming up with the bullet points.

Comment: So you want it to be a "sticky" *horizontal* navbar?

Comment: Your css in no way related you your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have in the comments "the CSS you provided has nothing to do with navigation bar" But If you want to make your navigation bar sticky at top then use the following CSS to make your navigation bar fixed at top:

```css
#stickynavbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="stickynavbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="home" href="LINK">Home</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
    <li><a title="TITLE" href="LINK">PAGE TITLE</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for me in a tester blog but not for my main blog, there must be something going wrong in my template thats overriding it